# First time trying autocomplete

Tags: c#, jquery, autocomplete, razor-pages

I am trying to create autocomplete box for CategoryName and it is not working. After searching through many topics here I decided to create my own.

My Controller command:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SDMan.Context;
using SDMan.Models;
using SDMan.Services.Interfaces;

namespace SDMan.Controllers
{
    public class IncidentController : Controller
    {
        //private readonly SignInManager<UserModel> signInManager;
        private readonly IIncidentService _modelService;
        private readonly IPriorityService _priorityService;
        private readonly ICategoryService _categoryService;
        private readonly IDepartmentService _departmentService;
        private readonly SDManDbContext _context;
        public IncidentController(IIncidentService modelService, IDepartmentService departmentService, ICategoryService categoryService, IPriorityService priorityService, SDManDbContext context)
        {
            _priorityService = priorityService;
            _categoryService = categoryService;
            _departmentService = departmentService;
            _modelService = modelService;
            _context = context;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {   //Po utworzeniu userów
            //var user = User.Identity.Name;
            //var modelData = _modelService.GetAll().Where(x => x.UserId == user);
            //Przed utworzeniem userow
            var modelData = _modelService.GetAll();
            return View(modelData);
        }
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            IncidentModel model = new IncidentModel();
            //model.ListPriorites = new SelectList(_modelService.GetAll(), model.Priority);
            //model.ListPriorites = new SelectList(_modelService.GetAll().ToList());
            model.ListPriorities = new SelectList(_priorityService.GetAll().Select(x => x.Name).ToList(), model.PriorityName);
            model.ListDepartments = new SelectList(_departmentService.GetAll().Select(x => x.Name).ToList(), model.DepartmentName);
            model.ListCategories = new SelectList(_categoryService.GetAll().Select(x => x.Name).ToList(), model.CategoryName);
            //model.ListPriorities = _priorityService.GetAll().ToList();
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm]IncidentModel model) //[FromForm] - potrzebne do mapowania danych z formularza na obiekt w przypadku gdy korzystamy z Razora lub zwykłego HTMLa. Przy taghelperach nie jest to konieczne tak jak w tym przypadku
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    //var user = await signInManager.UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.ToString());
                    //model.CreatedBy = model.ModifiedBy = user;
                    //model.UserId = User.Identity.Name;

                    // model.ListPriorites = new SelectList(_modelService.GetAll());

                    _modelService.Create(model);
                    //context.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return View(model);
                }
                return Redirect("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(model);
            }
        }
        public IActionResult Remove(int id)
        {
            return View(_modelService.Get(id));
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult RemoveConfirm(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                _modelService.Delete(id);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException);
                throw;
            }
            return Redirect("Index");
        }
        public IActionResult Edit(IncidentModel model,int id)
        {

            //model.ListPriorities = new SelectList(_priorityService.GetAll().Select(x => x.Name).ToList(), model.PriorityName);
            //model.ListDepartments = new SelectList(_departmentService.GetAll().Select(x => x.Name).ToList(), model.DepartmentName);
            //model.ListCategories = new SelectList(_categoryService.GetAll().Select(x => x.Name).ToList(), model.CategoryName);
            return View(_modelService.Get(id));
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult EditSave(IncidentModel model)
        {
            try
            {

                _modelService.Update(model);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException);
                throw;
            }
            return Redirect("Index");
        }
        public IActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            //IncidentModel model = new IncidentModel();
            //model.ListPriorities = new SelectList(_priorityService.GetAll().Select(x => x.Name).ToList(), model.PriorityName);
            //model.ListDepartments = new SelectList(_departmentService.GetAll().Select(x => x.Name).ToList(), model.DepartmentName);
            //model.ListCategories = new SelectList(_categoryService.GetAll().Select(x => x.Name).ToList(), model.CategoryName);
            return View(_modelService.Get(id));
        }
        public IActionResult Show()
        {
            var modelData = _modelService.GetAll();
            return View(modelData.Count());
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult CreateJS(string prefix)
        {
            var List = _categoryService.GetAll();
            var CatList = (from N in List
                            where N.Name.StartsWith(prefix)
                            select new { N.Name });
            return Json(CatList);

        }
    }
}
```

View with script:

```
@model SDMan.Models.IncidentModel
<h4>RecipeModel</h4>
<hr />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#CategoryName").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Incident/CreateJS",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { Prefix: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.CategoryName, value: item.CategoryName};
                        }))

                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            }
        });
    })
</script>



    <div class="col-md-16">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="form-horizontal">

                    <hr />

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CategoryName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            }
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="IncidentDescription" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="IncidentDescription" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="IncidentDescription" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>


            @*<div class="col-sm-3">
            <select asp-for="PriorityName" asp-items="Model.ListPriorities"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select asp-for="CategoryName" asp-items="Model.ListCategories"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select asp-for="DepartmentName" asp-items="Model.ListDepartments"></select>
        </div>*@
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Issue image:
[image]

In my DB I have inside Category table at this moment like 4 categories but when I type anything there is no popup. When I put breakpoints on my JsonResult CreateJS and go into Creating Incident nothing happens, like the action never started.

Comment: Time to do some debugging in the browser.  Are there any errors at all on the browser's development console?  In the debugging tools when you check the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  In the client-side code, is the `id` for the target element even `CategoryName`?  Can you replace your server-side code here with the resulting client-side code?

Comment: Thanks for response. Im in middle of creating my own app im just learning programming. In the network tab on post i have 302 error when i put anything on textbox for autocomplete.

Comment: 302 isn't an error.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status  Does the server respond with the data you expect?  This is a great time to start poking around the browser's debugging tools, there's a lot of information you can get there.

Comment: After edition i recieve Server error 500 "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints."

Comment: Sounds like there's more than one controller action with the same name?

Comment: Ok i have pasted whole controller. Yes there are two controllers. The thing is i want to call in autocomplete box one of categories to create incident with chosen category by user. OK i have changed Create to CreateJS and in script Incident/Create to Incident/CreateJS now i have in network response proper answer but there is no dropdownlist under autocompletebar.

Comment: What specifically is the data being returned?  In the controller it looks like you return a list of objects with a `Name` property, but in the JavaScript you're expecting a list of objects with a `CategoryName` property.

Comment: I am trying to assign to CategoryName in Incident Table Category Name from Category Table. Thats why i am calling. I am trying to get string data. CategoryName and Name are strings.

Comment: Well, the properties need to be the same.  If you're returning an object with the property `Name` then in the client-side code you need to use the property `Name`.  You can't use a property that isn't there.

Comment: I have resolved few issues thanks to you and now in network tab in return tab i see when i put in text box "S" i get in return "Software" there is for post status 200. But in the textbox tere is still only S letter and no dropdownlist or somthing like this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/48a03.png